# How is it possible to take a slice this way?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm taking a course in machine learning and there was a recommendation (about making a balancing of classes) to use the following code:

```
X_train_to_add = X_train[y_train.as_matrix() == 1, :][indices_to_add, :]
```

where `y_train` is a pandas dataframe (which is converted there to the numpy array via `as.matrix()`). I don't get how it is possible to use matrix as an index for slicing.

Comment: That's called [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

Comment: From SO documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/numpy/1296/the-basics/6738/boolean-indexing#t=201607250121018073291

Comment: That's not a *string*. That's *code*, or maybe you are referring to the *syntax*. A string is a type of data like `"here is some text"`. Don't use it with other meanings when asking about programming.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to break down the statement into its component parts.  This statement is equivalent to the following sequence of statements:

```
y = y_train.as_matrix()
row_mask = y == 1
X_masked = X_train[row_mask,:]
X_train_to_add = X_masked[indices_to_add, :]
```

Let's look at a concrete example.  Let's suppose `y`, `X_train`, and `indices_to_add` have the following values:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, -1, 1, 1])
>>> X_train = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
>>> indices_to_add = np.array([2, 0])
```

First, we create a boolean array indicating which elements of `y` are equal to `1`, which we'll call the "row mask".

```
>>> row_mask = y == 1
>>> row_mask
array([ True, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Next, we use the row mask to select the rows of `X_train` such that the corresponding values of `row_mask` are `True` (or equivalently, the rows such that the corresponding values of `y` are equal to `1`).

```
>>> X_masked = X_train[row_mask,:]
>>> X_masked
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])
```

Finally, we use an array of indices to select certain rows from the previous result.  Note that these indices refer to rows of `X_masked`, not the original matrix `X_train`.

```
>>> X_train_to_add = X_masked[indices_to_add,:]
>>> X_train_to_add
array([[13, 14, 15],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
```

You can see some more examples of numpy indexing in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).